# Netty or java.net.Socket for green field project?

Tags: java, sockets, netty

When starting a green field project, is it recommended now to use Netty project instead of `java.net.Socket`?

When to use Netty and when to use java.net.Socket?

The project is to connect to Redis.

Comment: What kind of project are you starting? What do you need sockets or netty for?

Comment: So you want to create your own java client for redis instead of using existing?

Comment: Yes definitely! Not because the current libs aren't good but because I can! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Netty.

1. It is simple enough when you want to do synchronous operations (using OIO).
2. It is extensible through modifying the netty pipeline allowing you to easily modify or add to the behavior at runtime (which seems like something a redis client might want to do)
3. If you have to, you can switch to asynchronous operations (using NIO/NIO2/AIO) without having to modify all your handlers. (hint:  you probably want to implement the Redis marshallers/unmarshallers as netty channel handlers).

I implemented just the SUB (as in PUB/SUB) for a redis java client, and it is nice to not have to block when you're subscribing.

Answer (score 2):

One is synchronous and the other asynchronous, so you need to make the choice how you want to program. The synchronous way is more obvious in the simple case, but usually the asynchronous approach wins as the requirements get tougher. Async is the definite winner in thriftyness with system resources and also in flexibility. To that, Netty is on its own a great, modern Java library.

Comment: Since redis is all about performance, I say netty is a great match for it.

Comment: Even if Netty is Asynchronous?

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "even if". Do you imply that asynchronous equals less performant?